# getting an error " can't covert text to int " in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services

HERE IS THE QUERY

--DECLARE @APSDONRFOR int`

--SET @APSDONRFOR = 2 
 `IF(@APSDONRFOR = 1)`
 
BEGIN 
SELECT  INVESTIGATION.ID 
,IR.ASSESSID 
,REVIEWDATE  
,INVESTIGATION.STARTDATE  
,INVESTIGATION.ENDDATE  
,INVESTIGATION.AllegedVictimName 
,INVESTIGATION.WorkerName 
,INVESTIGATION.SupervisorName 
,INVESTIGATION.AAA_District 
,INVESTIGATION.REGION 
,DONR.CATEGORY 
,DONR.DONRFUNCTION 
,DONR.COMMENT 
,DONR.LOI 
,DONR.UMN

`,DONRFOR = 'INVESTIGATION'`
 `,IR.SCREENDESIGNID`
`FROM IncidentReview IR` 
   `Left join(SELECT CATEGORY,DONRFUNCTION,COMMENT,LOI,UMN, ASSESSID`

```
            FROM (Select CATEGORY ='ADL', DONRFUNCTION ='Eating', IR.ASSESSID, Comment, LOI, UMN`
```

`FROM IncidentReview IR`
`LEFT JOIN (SELECT ASSESSID, SCALE,COMMENT = CASE WHEN`
`CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),ITEM) = '' THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),ITEM) END` 
 `FROM IncidentDetReview IDR Where IDR.SCALEID=30085729`
`)Comment on IR.ASSESSID = Comment.ASSESSID`
`Left Join (SELECT ASSESSID, SCALE, LOI= CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) = ''`
`THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(INT,LEFT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM),1)) END /*,IRECENTDR = Row_Number()` 
`OVER(PARTITION BY IR.INCIDENTID, scaleid ORDER BY REVIEWDATE DESC, IR.ASSESSID DESC)*/` 
 `FROM IncidentDetReview IDR Where IDR.SCALEID=30085779`
`)LOI on IR.ASSESSID = LOI.ASSESSID`
`Left Join (SELECT ASSESSID, SCALE, UMN=CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) = ''`
`THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(INT,LEFT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM),1)) END` 
 `FROM IncidentDetReview IDR Where IDR.SCALEID=30085780`
 `)UMN on IR.ASSESSID = UMN.ASSESSID`
`

```
        UNION ALL`
```

`

```
            Select CATEGORY ='ADL', DONRFUNCTION ='Bathing', IR.ASSESSID, Comment, LOI, UMN`
```

`FROM IncidentReview IR`
`Left Join (SELECT ASSESSID, SCALE, COMMENT = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),ITEM) = ''`
`THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),ITEM) END /*Comment=Convert(varchar(255), ITEM)*/ FROM` 
`IncidentDetReview IDR Where IDR.SCALEID=30085733)Comment on IR.ASSESSID = Comment.ASSESSID`
 `Left Join (SELECT ASSESSID, SCALE, LOI=CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) = '' THEN NULL`
`ELSE CONVERT(INT,LEFT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM),1)) END FROM IncidentDetReview IDR Where`
`IDR.SCALEID=30085781)LOI on IR.ASSESSID = LOI.ASSESSID`
`Left Join (SELECT ASSESSID, SCALE, UMN=CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) = '' THEN NULL`
`ELSE CONVERT(INT,LEFT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM),1)) END FROM IncidentDetReview IDR Where` 
`IDR.SCALEID=30085782)UMN on IR.ASSESSID = UMN.ASSESSID`
`

```
     )DONR1`
```

`)DONR on IR.ASSESSID = DONR.ASSESSID`
`

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ASSESSID,SCALE,ADLIMPTOTAL = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM)= '' THEN NULL ELSE  CONVERT(INT,ITEM) END  
FROM INCIDENTDETREVIEW IDR WHERE IDR.SCALEID = 30085743 
)ADLImpairmentTotal ON IR.ASSESSID = ADLImpairmentTotal.ASSESSID

LEFT JOIN  
         (
SELECT ID = INCIDENT.INCIDENTID 
,STARTDATE = CAST(INCIDENT.STARTDATE AS DATE) 
,ENDDATE = CAST(INCIDENT.ENDDATE AS DATE) 
,INCIDENTReportDate = CAST(INCIDENT.REPORTDATE AS DATE) 
,REGION = CASE WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'A%' OR INCIDENT.REGION  LIKE 'A%') THEN 'ATLANTA REGION'
WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'CEN%' OR

`INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'CEN%' OR INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'CSRA' OR INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'CSRA%') THEN` 
`'CENTRAL SAVANNAH RIVER REGION' WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'COASTAL%' OR` 
`INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'COASTAL%') THEN 'COASTAL GEORGIA REGION'`
`WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'G%' OR`
`.REGION LIKE 'G%') THEN 'GEORGIA MOUNTAIN REGION' WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'HEART%' OR`
`INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'HEART%') THEN 'HEART OF GEORGIA REGION'`enter code here`WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'MIDDLE%' OR`
`.REGION LIKE 'MIDDLE%') THEN 'MIDDLE GEORGIA REGION'`
`

```
                                                    WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'NORTHEAST%' OR `
```

`INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'NORTHEAST%' OR INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'NE%' OR INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'NE%')` 
`THEN 'NORTHEAST GEORGIA REGION'`
`WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'NORTHWEST%'`
OR INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'NORTHWEST%' OR INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'NW%' OR INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'NW%')  THEN 'NORTHWEST GEORGIA        REGION' 
WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'River%' OR INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'River%') THEN 'RIVER VALLEY GEORGIA REGION' 
WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'SOUTHERN%' OR INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'SOUTHERN%') THEN 'SOUTHERN GEORGIA REGION' 
WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'SE%' OR INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'SE%' OR INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'SOUTHEAST%' OR INCIDENT.REGION LIKE `enter code here`'SOUTHEAST%') THEN 'SOUTHEAST GEORGIA      REGION' 
WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'SOUTHWEST%' OR INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'SOUTHWEST%' OR INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'SW%' OR INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'SW%') THEN 'SOUTHWEST GEORGIA       REGION' 
WHEN (INCIDENT.INCIDENTQUEUE LIKE 'THREE%' OR INCIDENT.REGION LIKE 'THREE%') THEN 'THREE RIVERS REGION' 
ELSE 'REGION UNAVAILABLE' 
END 
,AAA = Incident.IncidentQueue 
,AAA_Clean = CASE WHEN (Incident.Region = '' OR Incident.Region = NULL) AND (Incident.IncidentQueue = '' OR Incident.IncidentQueue = NULL ) THEN 'Missing'  
WHEN (Incident.IncidentQueue = '' OR  Incident.IncidentQueue = NULL )Then Incident.Region /* AND (Incident.Region <> NULL OR Incident.Region <> '' )*/  
ELSE Incident.IncidentQueue

`END`
 `,TripleA = COALESCE(Incident.IncidentQueue,Incident.Region)`
`

```
                         ,HisParticipant.participantid`
```

`,HisParticipant.entityid`
 `,Hisparticipant.entityname`
 `,HisParticipant.contacttype`
 `,HPNParticipantID = HisParticipantName.participantid`
 `,AllegedVictimName = HisParticipantName.FirstName + ' ' + HisParticipantName.LastName`
 `,Workers.APSWorkerType`
 `,AAA_District = Case When (Contact.District IS NULL OR Contact.District = '') Then 'MISSING' ELSE Contact.District END`
 `,County = HisParticipantAddress.County`
 `,Contact.contactid`
 `,WorkerName = Contact.FirstName + ' ' + Contact.LastName`
`,SupervisorName = CASE WHEN (CONVERT (VARCHAR,Supercontact.FirstName) IS`
`NULL OR CONVERT(VARCHAR,Supercontact.FirstName) = '') AND (CONVERT                                 (VARCHAR,Supercontact.LastName) = '' OR CONVERT (VARCHAR,Supercontact.LastName) IS NULL) THEN 'MISSING'`
   `ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,Supercontact.FirstName) +`
`' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Supercontact.LastName)`
 `END`
`

```
          From INCIDENT `
```

`Left Join HISParticipant`
`ON Incident.IncidentID = HISParticipant.EntityID AND HISParticipant.EntityName =`
`'Incident' AND  HISParticipant.ContactType = 'AllegedVictim'`
`Left Join HISParticipantName`
`ON HisParticipant.Participantid = HisParticipantName.participantID AND`
`HISParticipantName.Active = 'True' AND HisParticipant.PrimaryYN= 'True' AND Display = 'True'`
`Left Join HISParticipantAddress`
`ON HisParticipant.ParticipantID = HisParticipantAddress.ParticipantID AND`
`HISParticipantAddress.PrimaryYN = 'True' AND HISParticipantAddress.Active = 'True' AND HISParticipantAddress.Display = 'True' Left Join Workers`  
`  ON Incident.MemberID = WORKERS.MEMBERID AND Workers.Unit = 'APS' /*And workers.Active =

`'True'*/  Left Join (SELECT * FROM CONTACT WHERE DISTRICT LIKE 'DISTRICT%')Contact` 
 `ON Workers.ContactID = Contact.ContactID`
`Left Join SUPERVISORS`
`ON Workers.MEMBERID = Supervisors.MEMBERID AND supervisors.PRIMARYSUPER = 'TRUE' AND (SUPERVISORS.ENDDATE IS NULL OR SUPERVISORS.ENDDATE = '')AND SUPERVISORS.ACTIVE = 'TRUE'`   
           `LEFT JOIN WORKERS SUPERWORK`
 `ON Supervisors.SUPERVISOR = SUPERWORK.MEMBERID`
`LEFT JOIN CONTACT SUPERCONTACT`
`ON SUPERWORK.CONTACTID = SUPERCONTACT.CONTACTID AND SUPERWORK.Active = 'TRUE'`
`

```
          --Where Incident.FundCode = 'APS'`
```

`--Where IR.SCREENDESIGNID = 2105`
 `and Incident.FundCode = 'APS'`
 `--AND IR.REVIEWDATE BETWEEN (:Startdate) AND (:EndDate)`
`) INVESTIGATION ON IR.INCIDENTID = INVESTIGATION.ID`    
 `WHERE IR.SCREENDESIGNID = 2105`
 `AND INVESTIGATION.STARTDATE BETWEEN '1/1/2015' AND '1/31/2020'`
`

END

IF (@APSDONRFOR = 2)

BEGIN

SELECT RECENTREVIEWEDCASE.CASENO 
,RECENTREVIEWEDCASE.ASSESSID 
,RECENTREVIEWEDCASE.REVIEWDATE  
,STARTDATE 
,ENDDATE 
,AllegedVictimName 
,WorkerName 
,SupervisorName 
,AAA_District 
,REGION 
,CATEGORY 
,DONRFUNCTION 
,COMMENT 
,LOI 
,UMN

`

`

`

`

`

`,DONRFOR = 'CASE'`
`,SCREENDESIGNID`
`FROM (SELECT * FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT AR.CASENO,AR.ASSESSID ,AR.SCREENDESIGNID,REVIEWDATE =`
`CAST(AR.REVIEWDATE AS DATE) ,RECENTREVIEW = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY` 
`CASENO ORDER BY REVIEWDATE DESC,ASSESSID DESC)`
`FROM ASSESSMENTREVIEW AR WHERE AR.FUNDCODE = 'APS' AND`
`AR.STATUS = 'COMPLETE'  )RECENTASSESSMENT WHERE RECENTREVIEW = 1`
 `)RECENTREVIEWEDCASE --AND CASENO = 273274`
`

INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID = O.CASENO 
,O.FUNDCODE 
,STARTDATE = CAST(O.OPENDATE AS DATE) 
,ENDDATE = CAST(O.CLOSEDATE AS DATE) 
,O.DISPOSITION 
,'AllegedVictimName' = C.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + C.LASTNAME 
,'WorkerName' = WC.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + WC.LASTNAME 
,'SupervisorName' = SC.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + SC.LASTNAME 
,AAA_District = CASE WHEN (SC.DISTRICT IS NULL OR SC.DISTRICT = '') THEN  '*MISSING*' ELSE SC.DISTRICT END 
,REGION = R.REGION 
FROM OPENCLOSE O 
LEFT JOIN DEMOGRAPHICS D  
ON O.CASENO = D.CASENO  
LEFT JOIN CONTACT C 
ON D.CONTACTID = C.CONTACTID  
LEFT JOIN WORKERS W 
ON O.PRIMARYWORKERID = W.MEMBERID 
LEFT JOIN CONTACT WC   
ON W.CONTACTID = WC.CONTACTID 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUPERVISOR, MEMBERID  
FROM SUPERVISORS WHERE PRIMARYSUPER = 'TRUE' AND  (SUPERVISORS.ENDDATE IS NULL OR SUPERVISORS.ENDDATE = '')AND SUPERVISORS.ACTIVE = 'TRUE' 
)S ON W.MEMBERID = S.MEMBERID 
LEFT JOIN WORKERS SW 
ON S.SUPERVISOR = SW.MEMBERID 
LEFT JOIN CONTACT SC   
ON SW.CONTACTID = SC.CONTACTID 
LEFT JOIN (Select DISTINCT HP.Region, HP.District, HP.County, HP.StateAbrev From  HISPlace HP Where HP.StateAbrev='GA' and HP.Active='True' 
)R ON C.RESCOUNTY = R.County

```
        WHERE O.FUNDCODE = 'APS'`
```

`) ONGCASE ON RECENTREVIEWEDCASE.CASENO = ONGCASE.ID  AND (RECENTREVIEWEDCASE.ScreenDesignID =`
`2081 OR RECENTREVIEWEDCASE.ScreenDesignID = 1854)`
`

LEFT JOIN (

SELECT CATEGORY,DONRFUNCTION,COMMENT,LOI,UMN,CASENO  
FROM (

SELECT SCREENDESIGNID,REVIEW,REVIEWDATE,CATEGORY,DONRFUNCTION,ASSESSID,COMMENT,LOI,UMN,CASENO  
FROM(SELECT * FROM (SELECT Category='ADL', DONRFunction='Transfer', AR.ASSESSID, Comment,  LOI,UMN,CASENO,STATUS,FUNDCODE,REVIEW,REVIEWDATE,SCREENDESIGNID 
,RECENT = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY AR.CASENO ORDER BY AR.REVIEWDATE  DESC,AR.ASSESSID DESC) 
FROM ASSESSMENTREVIEW AR 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ASSESSID, SCALE,LOI = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) = '' THEN  
NULL ELSE LEFT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM),2) END FROM ASSESSMENTDetReview ADR Where ADR.SCALEID =  30062203)LOI ON AR.ASSESSID = LOI.ASSESSID 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ASSESSID, SCALE,UMN = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) = '' THEN  NULL ELSE LEFT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM),2)END FROM ASSESSMENTDetReview ADR Where ADR.SCALEID = 30062204)UMN ON AR.ASSESSID = UMN.ASSESSID  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ASSESSID, SCALE,COMMENT = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),ITEM) = ''  THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),ITEM)END FROM ASSESSMENTDetReview ADR  Where ADR.SCALEID = 30062149  )COMMENT ON AR.ASSESSID = COMMENT.ASSESSID  
WHERE AR.ScreenDesignID = 1854 AND AR.FUNDCODE = 'APS' 
) E WHERE E.RECENT = 1  
)EE

----SCORE FROM SCREENDESIGNID 2081

```
        UNION ALL`
```

`

SELECT SCREENDESIGNID,REVIEW,REVIEWDATE,CATEGORY,DONRFUNCTION,ASSESSID,COMMENT,LOI,UMN,CASENO FROM  (SELECT * FROM ( SELECT Category='ADL', DONRFunction='EATING', AR.ASSESSID, Comment,  LOI,UMN,CASENO,STATUS,FUNDCODE,REVIEW,REVIEWDATE,SCREENDESIGNID  
,RECENT = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY AR.CASENO ORDER BY AR.REVIEWDATE DESC,AR.ASSESSID DESC) 
FROM ASSESSMENTREVIEW AR 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ASSESSID,SCALE,LOI = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) = '' THEN NULL ELSE  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM),1)END FROM ASSESSMENTDETREVIEW ADR WHERE ADR.SCALEID = 30083264 )LOI ON  AR.ASSESSID = LOI.ASSESSID 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ASSESSID,SCALE,UMN = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) = '' THEN NULL ELSE  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM),1)END FROM ASSESSMENTDETREVIEW ADR WHERE ADR.SCALEID = 30083265 )UMN ON  AR.ASSESSID = UMN.ASSESSID  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ASSESSID,SCALE,COMMENT = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) = '' THEN NULL ELSE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),ITEM)END FROM ASSESSMENTDETREVIEW ADR WHERE ADR.SCALEID = 30083214 )COMMENT ON  AR.ASSESSID = COMMENT.ASSESSID WHERE AR.ScreenDesignID = 2081 AND AR.FUNDCODE = 'APS' ) E WHERE E.RECENT  = 1 )EE1 --WHERE EE1.CASENO IN (123894,253179,233200)

)CDONR --WHERE (SCREENDESIGNID = 2081 OR SCREENDESIGNID = 1854) --AND FUNDCODE = 'APS'

)CASEDONR ON ONGCASE.ID = CASEDONR.CASENO AND (SCREENDESIGNID = 2081 OR SCREENDESIGNID = 1854)

INNER JOIN ( 
-- DONRTOTALS FROM BOTTOM OF THE SCREEN 2081 
SELECT CASENO ,ADLIMPTOTAL - -,ADLUMNTOTAL,IADLIMPTOTAL,IADLUMNTOTAL,TOTALLOI,TOTALUMN,DONRTOTAL, 
FROM( SELECT AR.CASENO 
,AR.ASSESSID 
,ADLIMPTOTAL 
FROM ASSESSMENTREVIEW AR  
INNER JOIN( 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT REVIEW,CASENO,AR.ASSESSID,SCALE,ADLIMPTOTAL = CASE WHEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) = '' THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) END

```
                                                                   ,RECENTDR = Row_Number()
```

`OVER(PARTITION BY AR.CASENO ORDER BY AR.REVIEWDATE DESC, AR.ASSESSID DESC)` 
`FROM ASSESSMENTREVIEW AR`
`JOIN ASSESSMENTDETREVIEW ADR ON AR.ASSESSID`
`= ADR.ASSESSID` 
`WHERE SCREENDESIGNID = 2081 AND SCALEID =`
`30083228 AND STATUS = 'Complete' AND FUNDCODE = 'APS'`
`
)DR WHERE RECENTDR = 1 --and caseno = 273274

`)ADLImpairmentTotal ON AR.ASSESSID =`
`ADLImpairmentTotal.ASSESSID` 
`

```
             UNION ALL  -- DONRTOTALS FROM BOTTOM OF THE SCREEN 1854`
```

`

```
            SELECT AR.CASENO`
```

`,AR.ASSESSID`
 `,ADLImpairmentTotal1.ADLIMPTOTAL`
`

```
            FROM ASSESSMENTREVIEW AR `
```

`INNER JOIN(SELECT * FROM (SELECT CASENO,AR.ASSESSID,SCALE,ADLIMPTOTAL = CASE WHEN`
`CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) = '' THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM) END`
`,RECENTDR = Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY AR.CASENO`
`ORDER BY AR.REVIEWDATE DESC, AR.ASSESSID DESC)` 
`FROM ASSESSMENTREVIEW AR`
`JOIN ASSESSMENTDETREVIEW ADR ON AR.ASSESSID = ADR.ASSESSID`
`WHERE SCREENDESIGNID = 1854 AND SCALEID = 30062158 AND STATUS`
`= 'Complete'AND FUNDCODE = 'APS')DR WHERE RECENTDR = 1` 
`)ADLImpairmentTotal1 ON AR.ASSESSID = ADLImpairmentTotal1.ASSESSID` 
`

```
      )DONRTOTAL1`
```

`)DONRTOTAL ON CASEDONR.CASENO = DONRTOTAL.CASENO`
 `WHERE (RECENTREVIEWEDCASE.ScreenDesignID = 2081 OR RECENTREVIEWEDCASE.ScreenDesignID = 1854)`
 `AND`
 `RECENTREVIEWEDCASE.REVIEWDATE BETWEEN '1/1/2015' AND '1/31/2020'--BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE`
`

END

1. `enter code here`

enter code here

Comment: wow.. you expect someone to actually read this the way it is? Have you tried to break your code down to bits to see where it is falling over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conversion of `text` data type to int is not possible. [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

`CONVERT(INT,LEFT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,ITEM),1))` this may work only if `LEFT` function on `ITEM` column is resulting in an integer value.
Check the data in ITEM Column.